# In a need of data in between dates SQL + Java

Tags: java, sql, date, between

```
select  sum(zetable)   
                 from    moneys                              
                 where   socialnumber = '" + socialnumber + "'                    
                 and     identifier = '" + id + "'            
                 and     salary in ('3333','3322','2222','2211')     
                 and     startdate <= stardatesalary            
                 and     (enddate >=  enddatesalary       
                 or      enddate is null)
```

So my problem is that while I do get salaries correctly with this from start date of the salary. I should be looking with start date of the month we are trying to get the salary from. for example if salary goes from june 16 to july 16 and another from july 28 to 28. Looking these up with salary gets me from june to july. And if I look up with july 1-31 I get from july 1 to 31 but then the data is all in one pile it does not work as intended.

So I kind of need the end date of the salary period and start date in between the month I am looking for data in as in it would cut the june to july salary @ 30 june and only count 1-16july. And they will need to be separate cause else it will mess up with loads of things.

I hope I am clear with this. Just been trying to come up with a solution in SQL not quite sure how to do this yet.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Curious as to what this has to do with Java.

Comment: I have *no* idea what you are actually asking. Please rephrase your question more clearly. -- From what I seem to have read, one crude approach can be to `group by` the *month* of the start and/or end date only.

Comment: Oracle db. Well the java is there to do many different searches depending on what I am looking for. As I have an web interface where I put the dates and I bring em through Java to the sql.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to join your result with a Date dimension table (one that contains one row per Date). For every row you'd show the salary for that particular day (I.e. dividing the full salary with the number of days that salary period is covering). Then you group and sum up this new column.

Easy :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem was more on the Java side of things. I made comparison of dates in try with if statement and now it gets the things I want, well sort of. Still not getting a total Sum for two dates that go on top of each other but I shall solve it and post results. Then post the finished crap code.